# Associations between 3 models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up the associations for my models and rails, and hit something I haven't been able to figure out with the documentation

My Tables:

```
groups
  id

group_users
  group_id
  user_id

group_messages
  group_user_id
  message
```

I would like to be able to find group_messages with a group.  One way is to find all group_users in the group, then search for group_messages from those group_user_id's, but I don't think that would be the most efficient.  Is there a better way to set this up so I can search for group_messages directly with the group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GroupMessage.joins(:group_user).where(['group_users.group_id = ?', my_group.id])